# mongodb memory confusion. page fault and index size

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm utterly confused on how much actual memory is being used by my mongodb..

issuing db.stats(1024*1024) i get an output

```
> db.stats(1024*1024)
{
    "db" : "test",
    "collections" : 9,
    "objects" : 38035503,
    "avgObjSize" : 535.2138471259339,
    "dataSize" : 19414,
    "storageSize" : 22280,
    "numExtents" : 62,
    "indexes" : 12,
    "indexSize" : 4039,
    "fileSize" : 30642,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So i have a little less then 40 million objects and an index size of 4GB.
Running this on a windows server with 17GB RAM, looking at the Resource Monitor and task manager, my mongodb instance have a working set of 17GB and a Shareable of the same amount.

My first though was that "ok so it has pre-allocated datafiles so that there will be faster inserts when it actually needs the space".

But then i started mongostat and could clearly see a very much to high page fault:

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults
 time
   220   2419      0      0       0     221       0  27.9g  56.1g  16.8g   2659
```

So im guessing that it actually has run out of memory and is now swapping and picking up directly from disk.

My question basically is how can i actually determine the amount of data that i will be able to store before i run out of RAM?. The stats tell me that it only has 4GB worth of index, but mongo seems to be choked,swapping and consuming all 17GB. What am i missing?

Comment: Index size is Irrelevant. What matters is your working set size. The latest version of MongoDB does have a way to possibly calculate your working set size: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/#workingset though it can only give a rough estimation. Basically what you need to consider is: a. Are all my queries hitting indexes, b. Are my queries covered, if not how many documents am I paging into my working set within the given amount of time?

Comment: these are stats for a single db and mongostat is showing that you have 27.9G of data files.  Are there other DBs?  Is replication on?

Comment: @Sammaye you are off the mark again. data and index size have everything to do with it - what else do you think is taking up RAM?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky A working set does not consist of only your indexes though, as the OP seems to think?

Comment: it's data size plus index size. how does that make index size irrelevant?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I have found that you don't always need to fit your indexes into RAM, it depends on the queries and what parts of the indexes they use in turn. So my working set, as I have observed, can be a range of an index and then some documents.

Comment: So this is only 1 database running on 1 instance, no cluster or shards or replicas.

One of my indexes is on a timestamp, something that is a required search parameter in my application, so im guessing that most of my queries should be hitting that index.

Comment: I have notiuced you are getting over 2.4k queries to this single machine. This could be containing data that is expanding your working set, though I am noticing this is without updates. Are you only reading your data?

Comment: @Sammaye, this snapshot from mongostat is from when i was inserting a high amount of data that does a lot of consecutive queries as it does so.

Comment: Oh I misread your mongostat output :\ I read it as `insert time` lol when it was actually `insert`

Answer (score 2):

You have 17GB of RAM available for about 20GB of data plus 4GB of indexes (and that's just on this DB - I don't know if there is more in your system, but mongostat says you have total datafile size of about 28GB).

If you are querying over your entire dataset, wouldn't you expect that eventually new data records being read can no longer fit into RAM without displaying some of the previously read (and loaded into RAM) records?  That's what you're seeing with page faulting.

It's not data storage that you are concerned about, it's data being used or queries or accessed.  If it all can't stay in RAM then it will get swapped out and then will need to be swapped back in when accessed again.